# Average behaviour of a system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, time-evolution

A system which is in a macro state may be in any of  a large no. of microstates at a particular instant of time. But we see an average behaviour of the system. I don't understand why it is so ? Why don't we see the instantaneous state of the system ?

Answer (score 0):

These instananeous states do happen. But the idea behind statistical physics is that in equilibrium, we can describe the system using a small number of variables. For example let's consider a box of volume $V$. One possible microstate is that all the particles collect in half of the box so the volume of the gas is $V/2$. But according to statistical physics this is *incredibly* unlikely. So this will never happen (realistically). The system cycles through every possible microstate but because of the large number of particles the properties of the system only take on some values that are determined by the average.

Another example could be a large number of coins. Imagine these are constantly flipped. Heads will be represented by $1$ and tails by $0$. If you have a really large number of coins the average value will be about $1/2$. The actual value will fluctuate about $1/2$ because all the coins are constantly flipping but once you have $6.022\cdot 10^{23}$ coins, like in many macroscopic systems, the fluctuations will be neglible to many decimal places. In that case the average of the value can be represented by an average over many systems.